# Sequelize find all data not in Junction Table

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have a Question table full of questions and a User table which has a list of my Users. They have a many to many relationship that has a Junction table Question_User with foreign key uid(userid) and qid(questionid).

When I user answers a question I record it in Question_User so that I know which users have answered which question. It records the users id and the id of the question they answered.

I want to query for every question a particular user HAS NOT answered.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Question = sequelize.define("Question", {
    qid: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    unique: true
  },
  question: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  },
  option1: DataTypes.STRING,
  option2: DataTypes.STRING,
  option3: DataTypes.STRING,
  option4: DataTypes.STRING,
  option5: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Question.belongsToMany( models.User, {
          through: 'Question_User',
          foreignKey: 'qid'
        });
      }
    }
  });

  return Question;
};

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    uid: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      unique: true
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        User.belongsToMany( models.Question, {
          through: 'Question_User',
          foreignKey: 'uid'
        });
      }
    }
  });

  return User;
};

Models.Question.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Models.User,
      through: {
        attributes: ['uid', 'qid']
      }
   }]
})
```

This adds a Users array with all the users that have answered that question on to the question that is returned from the query.

Comment: Can you work along `SELECT
  U.user_id
  , Q.question_id
FROM User U, Question Q
WHERE (user_id, question_id) NOT IN (SELECT user_id, question_id FROM User_Question)
ORDER BY user_id, question_id
;` as in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6dcd1d/1)?